# CMake can not see SDL2_PATH environment variable (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I would like to build a project, which uses SDL2. I downloaded the windows development package of SDL2, put it to `D:\lib\SDL2-2.0.10`, and set the `SDL2_PATH` environment variable to this path.

The project uses [FindSDL2.cmake](https://github.com/tcbrindle/sdl2-cmake-scripts/blob/master/FindSDL2.cmake) to find the library, where `${SDL2_PATH}` is listed in `SDL2_SEARCH_PATHS`.

If I try to run CMake, it is not able to find SDL2. The environment variable is correctly set, I checked it with `echo $env:SDL2_PATH` in powershell.

But it I put this line at the beginning of `CMakeLists.txt`, then it works:

```
set(SDL2_PATH "D:\\lib\\SDL2-2.0.10")
```

Why is CMake not able to see the `SDL2_PATH` environment variable? What do I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `FindSDL2.cmake` file looks for the CMake variable `${SDL2_PATH}`, which you must define in the CMake file yourself. Without defining it, this variable will be **empty**. See the code here from this file:

```
SET(SDL2_SEARCH_PATHS
    ~/Library/Frameworks
    /Library/Frameworks
    /usr/local
    /usr
    /sw # Fink
    /opt/local # DarwinPorts
    /opt/csw # Blastwave
    /opt
    ${SDL2_PATH}
)
```

We can tell CMake to read an [environment variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/ENV.html), with the `ENV` syntax, in order to import an environment variable's contents into CMake.

Therefore, try putting this at the beginning of your CMake instead:

```
set(SDL2_PATH $ENV{SDL2_PATH})
```

---

The `FindSDL2.cmake` file *does* read the `SDL2DIR` environment variable. So, rather than setting `SDL2_PATH` in your CMake file, you can simply set the `SDL2DIR` environment variable instead.